# How to submit updated version of ios app on appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I am new in ios and there is allredy a older version of ios app on appstore.
i am created new one with some changes. Now i want to submit that app on appstore please tell me complete procedure of submiting update of app on appstore. also i want to know how to create that app binary that needs for uploding.

Answer (score 9):

First you need to increase the app version than previous one. You can change it from Xcode.

[image]

Then go to the iTunes Connect and create a new version. New version number and Xcode version number must be same.

[image]

Then provide all the details and upload it from Xcode, same as you have already done it for earlier version.

To upload from Xcode do the below

1. Change the device to `iOS Device` or any real device. `Simulator` will not work here.
2. From the menu Product > Archive

[image]

3. Validate and submit

[image]

> ***N.B.: In order to upload in App Store you have to provide all the
>   required assets, a valid provision profile and other informations.***

Comment: is there need of change build version also?

Comment: Yes. You have to increase the build version.

Comment: Is there a way to submit an update without re-entering all of the meta-data, screenshots, etc.? I just want to update the physical build.

Comment: No need to enter all the metadata while updating the new version of your build on itunes. you can also update new version of your build using Application Loader.

Comment: @NitheeshGeorge: There is absolutely no need to increase the build number. If you change the version number it makes no sense to increase the build number for the increased version number.